# JQMobile - Styling H1/span/div texts

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have this

```
<h1 id="coins"></h1>
```

But cant style it with css, when i use Jquery Mobile ?

```
.coins{
font-family: Verdana;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 50px;
color: #ecb502;
margin: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
}
```

have also tryed with `h1{}` and didnt help ?

anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're styling an id using a period '.' then that's your problem.  Style *ids* with a hash '#' and *classes* with a period '.'

Also, you would use font-weight: bold instead of font-style.  font-style would be for italicizing, primarily.

And, although it is more of a preference thing, as an FYI you don't *need* to specify units for the values of 0 on your margin.  Zero times anything is still zero, doesn't matter what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to be more specific on your selector so that it over-writes the jQuery Mobile CSS (which targets the `<h1>` elements in `<div data-role="header">` elements with: `.ui-header .ui-title`):

Change:

```
.coins{
```

To:

```
/*this selects all elements that have both the `ui-title` and the `coins` classes and is a descendant of an element with the `ui-header` class*/
.ui-header .ui-title.coins{
```

Remember that the rule with most specific selector will be used in CSS.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdP7S/2/